# Can Random Forest regressor or Decision trees handle missing values and outliers?

Tags: machine-learning, python, random-forest, data-science-model, missing-data

I have below assumptions about RF & Decision trees in general, please correct me if the assumptions are incorrect.

1. It takes care of missing values
2. It handles outliers
3. It handles skewness in the data so the transformation is not required.
4. Feature scaling is not required
5. Feature selection is not required.

Please correct if my observations are incorrect as you can see there is a nan value error in the dataset. Also how to rectify it?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
```

## importing dataset

```
share3.info()
share2.isnull().sum()


XRD = share2.drop(['Close'], axis = 1)
YRD = share2['Close']
```

## training & test set

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_trainRD, X_testRD, Y_trainRD, Y_testRD = train_test_split(XRD,YRD,test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)
```

## fitting random forest regresson to the dataset

````
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators= 350,random_state = 0)
regressor.fit(X_trainRD, Y_trainRD)

***ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32')***
```
````

Comment: I feel like the five points should be separate questions, and indeed most(/all) of them are answered elsewhere on this site and stats.SE.

Answer (score 1):

**No, not all of your assumptions are true**

**1. Missing values**

The sklearn implementation of RandomForest does not handle missing values internally without clear instructions/added code. So while remedies (e.g. missing value imputation, etc.) are readily available within sklearn you DO have to deal with missing values before training the model.

This involves understanding how and why values are missing (MCAR VS. MAR VS. ...) and determining the best way to deal with those values (median/mean imputation, MICE, removing values, etc.).

**2. Outliers and Skewness**

Again this isn't a done deal! You need some EDA to understand your data here and handle it accordingly. Strong biases in the distribution of the dependend variable (so-called class imbalances) can heavily influence the result. Look into ways to handle those like SMOTE.

Outliers are less of a problem, granted they really ARE outliers. Check via EDA and confirm this isn't a problem to be dealt with.

**3. Feature selection and transformation**

It is true that many ML models favor a more-is-more approach to feature selection. The main benefit of using RandomForest, XGB over classical statistical approaches is that they cope much better with irrelevant predictors.

Still feature selection also means feature engineering which is still helpful and necessary. Additionally for practical purposes you should still aim to reduce predictor amount if you want to use your model again. Because no matter how irrelevant every predictor used in the training model NEEDS TO BE PRESENT in the unseen data as well.

Lastly you will need to transform data! Simply example, RandomForest needs one-hot-encoding (OHE) for factor variables and string variables. You do not need the same scale for all your numerical variables but they all need to be numerical!

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, I have a question in Transformation, so do we have to log transformation or other transformation to convert the data into a normal distribution.

Comment: @yathislax No, log transformation or transformations to get specific distributions, unify scales, etc. are not needed (this includes but is not limited to centering, normalization, etc.). But you will have to one-hot-encode any non-numeric variables and perform other basic data tidying work.

Comment: +1, but: missingness and categorical features needing dealt with is specific to sklearn, not tree models in general; class imbalance is not necessarily a problem; _nonmonotonic_ feature transformations may be helpful.

Comment: @BenReiniger yes this is an abridged answer because otherwise it would way more "it depends". However as OP specifically asked about RF I feel this is fine. In the end you always need EDA and you need to understand your data and judge it accordingly, no algorithm can take that 100% of your hands.

Comment: You don't need to correct for class imbalance and it's not encouraged since it will remove meaning from the probabilities you are estimating. Instead, you can adjust the probability threshold for classification. Please see this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.09101

Answer (score 1):

**It takes care of missing values**

 No, Infact no model can handle NaN, if any model is doing so, it is taking a decision on your behalf. NaN must be understood(reason) and resolved

**It handles outliers**

Yes, as it doesn't depend on any distance formula or any maths formula minimization, it simply tries split on different data/feature and checks the improvement 

**It handles skewness in the data so the transformation is not required.**

Yes, for the same reason 

**Feature scaling is not required**

Yes, for the same reason. Even One-Hot is not needed for categorical features, simply label encoding will work 

**Feature selection is not required**.

No, this is a very different aspect. With too many features and data size, it will be difficult for the model to search the best split. Must do if count is very high

**Class imbalance**

Have to be handled. because Class imbalance means data didn't provide ample opportunity to a model to learn about the minority class. Nothing to do with Model. All model will have a challenge.

**Overfit**

DT yes, RF is safe

Comment: Missing values can be dealt with by tree models, though not in sklearn.  Label encoding unordered categorical features is not advised, although depending on the situation it may be OK.  I disagree that class imbalance is necessarily a problem.  Overfitting is certainly a problem to be thinking about with random forests.  On outliers/skewness/scale I agree.